# Classification/Regression Tree with nonngeative response

Tags: generalized-linear-model, random-forest, cart

I try to model the duration until a unit is inspected by a large number of possible explanatory variables.
The duration is non-negative and the explanatory variables are factors and numerical variables.

If I knew the best explanatory variables then I would use `glm` in R. I find family "Gamma" with link "log" appropriate for modelling something like a waiting time.

Can I combine trees and `glm` in R? E.g. with `randomForest` I can use a formula but the regression is a simple linear model (like `lm`). Thanks!